# Где в коде есть ошибка?

Tags: python, tkinter, время

```
    from tkinter import*
import random
import time

class Ball:
    def __init__(self ,canvas ,paddle ,color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.paddle = paddle
        self.id = canvas.create_oval(10,10, 25, 25, fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 245, 100)
        starts =[-3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3]
        random.shuffle(starts)
        self.x= starts[0]
        self.y = -3
        self.canvas_height = self.canvas.winfo_height()
        self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
        self.hit_bottom = False

    def hit_paddle(self, pos):
        paddle_pos = self.canvas.coords(self.paddle.id)
        if pos[2] >= paddle_pos[0] and pos[0] <= paddle_pos[2]:
            if pos[3] >= paddle_pos[1] and \
                    pos[3] <= padlle_pos[3]:
                return True
        return False

    def draw(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, self.y)
        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        if pos[1] <= 0:
            self.y = 3
        if pos[3] >= self.canvas_height:
            self.hit_bottom = True
        if self.hit_paddle(pos) == True:
            self.y = -3
        if pos[0] <= 0:
            self.x = 3
        if pos[2] >= self.canvas_width:
            self.x = -3
class Paddle:
    def __init__(self, canvas, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.id = canvas.create_rectangle(0,0, 100,10, fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 200, 300)
        self.x = 0
        self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
        self.canvas.bind_all('<a>',self.turn_left)
        self.canvas.bind_all('<d>',self.turn_right)
        
    def draw(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, 0)
        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        if pos[0] <= 0:
            self.x = 0
        elif pos[2] >= self.canvas.width:
            self.x = 0
    def turn_left(self, evt):
        self.x = -2

    def turn_right(self, evt):
        self.x = 2
      
tk=Tk()
tk.title("pocket tenis alfa")
tk.resizable(0, 0)
tk.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=500, height=400, bd=0, \
                highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack()
tk.update()

paddle = Paddle(canvas, 'blue')
ball = Ball(canvas,paddle, 'red')

while 1:
    if ball.hit_bottom == False:
        ball.draw()
        paddle.draw()
    tk.update_idletasks()
    tk.update()
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: Почему вы решили, что где-то здесь есть ошибка?

Comment: В заголовке вопроса!

Comment: Я уже сделал, чтобы мячик двигался. У вас ошибки: 1.В первой строке лишний отступ. 2. Строку `elif pos[2] >= self.canvas.width:` нужно заменить на `elif pos[2] >= self.canvas_width:`. Но всё равно в конце выдаёт ошибку. Пока буду дальше думать)

Answer (score 0):

- `elif pos[2] >= self.canvas.width:` - нужно подчёркивание вместо точки. Ведь переменная у вас зовётся `canvas_width`.
- `pos[3] <= padlle_pos[3]:` - опять название переменной. Везде у вас с двумя d и одним l, а в данной строчке наоборот. Правильно `paddle_pos`.

Comment: Всё равно ошибку в конце выдал

Comment: @ПИТОНИСТверсия3-8 Нет, больше ошибок не выдавало. Я даже поигрался в этот арканоид для слоупока :)

Comment: Странно, у меня выдало))) Видимо плохой интерпретатор